# Add summary columns to a pandas dataframe based on matching values in a different dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've got a DataFrame that indicates members of a project and the project start date, and a second DataFrame that indicates birth dates. I'm trying to add a number of columns indicating the total number of people in certain age groups based on the start of each project.

```
print(projects)
           Start  John  Bob  Gladys
Project                               
A     2014-01-08     1    0       0
B     2016-08-09     0    1       1
C     2018-02-06     0    1       0

print(birthdays)
             birth
name              
John    1983-04-06
Gladys  1969-08-02
Bob     1946-11-03
```

I've considered using `.apply()` or `.iterrows()` methods but I'm having a hard time even wrapping my head around where to start. The real DataFrames have significantly more columns and rows so I need to avoid needing to call any columns by name.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
              Start  John  Bob  Gladys  25-34  35-45  46-55  56+
Project                                                         
A        2014-01-08     1    0       0      1      0      0    0
B        2016-08-09     0    1       1      0      0      1    1
C        2018-02-06     0    1       0      0      0      0    1
```

Any suggestions on where to start?

Comment: Are you considering each person's age at their project start, or their age today? In either case, all of John, Bob, and Gladys are at most 36 years old, so should the example age groups `46-55` and `56+` be all zero?

Comment: You're right, I included the different dates than I calculated with. Updated, thanks. I'm looking at age at project start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) ,[`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt),[`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
##unpivot the dataframe keeping Start as index and keep only value ==1
melt_=projects.melt('Start').query('value==1') 
#map the variable column from above with our birthday` dataframe squeezed into a series. 
#Once mapped, subtract with the `Start` column to find out year difference.
Age=(melt_.Start-melt_.variable.map(birthdays.squeeze())).dt.days//365
#using pd.cut , we cut the Age into bins and assign our labels.
bins=[25,35,45,55,np.inf]
labels=['25-34','35-45','46-55','56+']
melt_=melt_.assign(Age=pd.cut(Age,bins,labels=labels))
```

Finally merge with original df with the `crosstab` output of `pd.crosstab(melt_.Start,melt_.Age)`:

```
projects.merge(pd.crosstab(melt_.Start,melt_.Age).reindex(columns=labels,fill_value=0)
                              ,left_on='Start',right_index=True)
```

---

```
              Start  John  Bob  Gladys  25-34  35-45  46-55  56+
Project                                                        
A       2014-01-08     1    0       0      1      0      0    0
B       2016-08-09     0    1       1      0      0      1    1
C       2018-02-06     0    1       0      0      0      0    1
```

**Note**: The expected output is wrong since `Bob` is elder and is `56+` as per project date.

Comment: I can not see definition of `bins ` and `labels` variables in your code. Could you, please, edit your answer and provide it?

Comment: I made this update to avoid issues with projects with the same start date:
melt_=pd.melt(projects, id_vars=['Project', 'Start']).query('value==1')
projects.merge(pd.crosstab(melt_.Project,melt_.Age).reindex(columns=labels,fill_value=0),left_on='Project',right_index=True)

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the desired result:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

#create the Projects dataframe
d1={'Projects': ['A', 'B','C'], 'Start': ['2014-01-08', '2016-08-09','2018-02-06'],'John':[1,0,0],'Bob':[0,1,1],'Gladys':[0,1,0]}
projects=pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
projects.set_index('Projects',inplace=True)

#create the Birthdays dataframe
d2={'name':['John','Bob','Gladys'],'birth':['1983-04-06','1946-11-03','1969-08-02']}
birthdays=pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
birthdays.set_index('name', inplace=True)

# Create the age slab dataframe with dummy values
d3={'Projects': ['A','B','C'], '25-34':[0,0,0], '35-45':[0,0,0], '46-55':[0,0,0], '56+':[0,0,0]}
age_slabs=pd.DataFrame(data=d3)
age_slabs.set_index('Projects',inplace=True)

#concatenate projects and age_slabs dataframe
concat=pd.concat([projects, age_slabs], axis=1)
concat=concat.copy()

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"

for i in range(len(concat)):

    val_John=((concat['John'][i]*(datetime.strptime(concat['Start'][i], date_format)-datetime.strptime(birthdays['birth'].John, date_format))).days)/365.
    val_Bob=((concat['Bob'][i]*(datetime.strptime(concat['Start'][i], date_format)-datetime.strptime(birthdays['birth'].Bob, date_format))).days)/365.
    val_Gladys=((concat['Gladys'][i]*(datetime.strptime(concat['Start'][i], date_format)-datetime.strptime(birthdays['birth'].Gladys, date_format))).days)/365.

    # check for conditions and set 1 or 0, and add up
    concat['25-34'][i] = 1 if ((val_John<=34) & (val_John>=25)) else 0 + 1 if ((val_Bob<=34) & (val_Bob>=25)) else 0 + 1 if ((val_Gladys<=34) & (val_Gladys>=25)) else 0
    concat['35-45'][i] = 1 if ((val_John<=45) & (val_John>=35)) else 0 + 1 if ((val_Bob<=45) & (val_Bob>=35)) else 0 + 1 if ((val_Gladys<=45) & (val_Gladys>=35)) else 0
    concat['46-55'][i] = 1 if ((val_John<=55) & (val_John>=46)) else 0 + 1 if ((val_Bob<=55) & (val_Bob>=46)) else 0 + 1 if ((val_Gladys<=55) & (val_Gladys>=46)) else 0
    concat['56+'][i] = 1 if ((val_John>=56)) else 0 + 1 if ((val_Bob>=56)) else 0 + 1 if ((val_Gladys>=56)) else 0

print (concat)
```

Output:

```
               Start  John  Bob  Gladys  25-34  35-45  46-55  56+
Projects                                                         
A         2014-01-08     1    0       0      1      0      0    0
B         2016-08-09     0    1       1      0      0      1    1
C         2018-02-06     0    1       0      0      0      0    1
```